# Spring @JmsListener is not able to convert json into object

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I was expecting @JmsListener will automatically convert json object into my object, but its payload is returning the data as string in json format rather than actual object.

```
    @JmsListener(destination = "${default-queue-name-to-listen}")
    public void receiveMessage(final Message<MyObject> message) throws JMSException {
        logger.info("message received from the queue/topic : {}", message);
        MyObject response = message.getPayload();
}
```

But we receive response in a String format like this: {"id":"1","name":"2222"}

And this is failing it at runtime.

My other piece of code is:

```
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws URLSyntaxException {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    return factory;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what the producer sent.

If a TextMessage was sent, you get a String. If an ObjectMessage sent, you can get an Object.